# Changing "name" in package.json crashes React DevTools (problem arises in cross-unzip)

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-react-boilerplate, electron-react

I'm quite new to React and electron, so I decided to learn it by creating a simple app. For this purpose I decided to use this boilerplate:
https://github.com/alexdevero/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate.
The only code I added is to get process.env.APPDATA, and if it exists (ie. if the program runs on Windows), I create a separate folder for my app (%APPDATA%\testapp) if it doesn't already exist, and save the current daytime to that folder in a JSON file (I use 'fs' for file/folder operations). The code is in App.js, and is executed on mount i.e. in `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])` That's all.
In this state, the application works exactly as I would expect. However, "interesting" things start to happen after I change the "name" field in the package.json file (I can change: description, version, license etc without any problems, only changing the name seems to be problematic).
First of all, after changing the name I get the following error when I try to run the app using either `yarn start` or `npm start`:

```
Error loading React DevTools:  Error: Exited with code 2
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\dev\testapp\node_modules\cross-unzip\index.js:38:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
```

Moreover, I've noticed that the folder %APPDATA%\testapp gets populated by files and folders that normally (i.e. when the "name" field is unchanged) don't show up there: "blob_storage", "Cache", "Code Cache", "extensions", "GPUCache" etc
[Files and folders created on error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTT5G.png)

I've already tried many solutions:

- I tried to add `new HtmlWebpackPlugin({title: "testapp"})` to both webpack.dev.config.js and webpack.build.config
- I tried to clear the cache (`yarn cache clean`), delete the lock files and node_modules folder, restart Windows and then run `yarn install` but it doesn't help either.
- The program starts to work normally (no errors, no files/folders created in %APPDATA%\testapp) only when I change the name back to "electron-react-webpack-boilerplate". But I would like to change this name and use one of my own!

Thank you in advance for your help!